# FFPLAY bindings or any wrapper for C#

Tags: c#, binding, videodisplay

I need to know first if it's possible to embed FFplay (from ffmpeg project) in an C# application, and is it possible to use it within a WinForms Control, because if yes than I can manipulate it by adding at a Panel Control.

I've seen some bindings using FFmpeg, but after using FFplay and hours of Googling nothing without success I decided to open a topic about that.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?  I'm looking to embed FFPlay in a WPF application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything about embedding FFplay in a C# application, but did find this question which is relevant as VideoLAN is based upon FFmpeg.

[Comparison of .NET Wrapper Libraries for libVLC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216102/comparison-of-net-wrapper-libraries-for-libvlc)

...and this points to a rather cool wrapper

[VideoLan DotNet for WinForm & WPF](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Cool stuff ,i have lot of experience embedding VLC in a C# Application using Windows Forms ,but for some Strange reasons from version 1.0.0 VLC ActiveX does not support Transcoding and Streaming so there where 2 options ,use the VLC Process and send Arguments via Process Object or downagree to 0.9 Grishenko .Anyway this stuff could be needful though ! Bests @ wonea